# No component from another module is displayed

Tags: angular

I tried display component with name **main**, using selector: 'app-main'. Component main is in NavbarModuleModule.

In NavbarModuleModule i make export main component.

I added **NavbarModuleModule** module to main module with name **app.module**.

Using selector I add him to main template but still component is not loaded.

[image]

**navbar-module.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MainComponent } from './main/main.component'; 

@NgModule({
  declarations: [MainComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule 
  ],
  exports : [MainComponent] 
})
export class NavbarModuleModule { }
```

**Main.component.html**

```
<p>main works!</p>
```

**main.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.scss']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**app.module.ts** - main module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { NavbarModuleModule } from './navbar-module/navbar-module.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";    

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
    HttpClientModule,
    NavbarModuleModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, HeaderComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong? How can I load this component with other module.

Comment: Where did you try to display the main component? What error / behavior are you getting?

Comment: I want to display main component in main index.html. There is no error, just is displayed nothing.

Comment: Why do u want to do it in index.html, you can have this in `app.component.html`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add your maincomponent in bootstrap array which is in Appmodule.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { NavbarModuleModule } from './navbar-module/navbar-module.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";    

@NgModule({
declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  HeaderComponent
],
imports: [
  BrowserModule, 
  HttpClientModule,
  NavbarModuleModule
],
providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, HeaderComponent, MainComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```